# why should i use .payment() in the following code?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.

is `this.payment` another property of the car object?

when i want to calculate the price of a car, for example:

```
var work_car_payments= work_car.payment();
```

why should i use `.payment()`?
`payment` hasn't been defined as a function in the code. I'm a little confused.

```
function get_payment() {
  var the_payment = 250;
  the_payment += (this.seats == "leather") ? 100 : 50;
  the_payment += (this.engine == "V-8") ? 150 : 75;
  the_payment += (this.theradio == "CD Player") ? 35 : 10;
  return the_payment;
}

function car(seats, engine, theradio) {
  this.seats = seats;
  this.engine = engine;
  this.theradio = theradio;
  this.payment = get_payment;
}
var work_car = new car("cloth", "V-6", "Tape Deck");
var fun_car = new car("leather", "V-8", "CD Player");
var custom_car = new car(fun_car.seats, work_car.engine, fun_car.theradio);
var work_car_payment = work_car.payment();
var fun_car_payment = fun_car.payment();
var custom_car_payment = custom_car.payment();
document.write("<h2>The information on the cars you requested:</h2>");
document.write("<strong>Work Car: </strong>");
document.write(work_car.seats + "," + work_car.engine + "," + work_car.theradio);
document.write("<br />");
document.write("<strong>Payments:</strong> $" + work_car_payment);
document.write("<p>");
document.write("<strong >Fun Car: </strong>");
document.write(fun_car.seats + "," + fun_car.engine + "," + fun_car.theradio);
document.write("<br />");
document.write("<strong>Payments:</strong> $" + fun_car_payment);
document.write("</p>");
document.write("<p>");
document.write("<strong>Custom Car: </strong>");
document.write(custom_car.seats + "," + custom_car.engine + ",");
document.write(custom_car.theradio);
document.write("<br />");
document.write("<strong>Payments:</strong> $" + custom_car_payment);
document.write("</p>");
```

Comment: _“payment hasn't been defined as a function in the code”_ — `payment` is a property on `car` referring to the function `get_payment`. That function has been declared in the code. As to “why” you should call that function: understand [how `this` works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/4642212).

Comment: `this.payment = get_payment` = whatever get_payment is.
Here, it's a function.
try `var get_payment = 1000000;` instead of `function get_payment` (comment it out just for this test), and you'll not be about to use `()`, and, when you use `somecar.payment` you'll get 1000000.

Answer (score 1):

`get_payment` is defined as a function.

The `car()` function contains:

```
this.payment = get_payment;
```

This defines the `payment` property as containing that function.

Note that the more common way to do this would be to assign the property in the `car` prototype, rather than assigning it to each object, since all cars get the same function.

```
function get_payment() {
  var the_payment = 250;
  the_payment += (this.seats == "leather") ? 100 : 50;
  the_payment += (this.engine == "V-8") ? 150 : 75;
  the_payment += (this.theradio == "CD Player") ? 35 : 10;
  return the_payment;
}

function car(seats, engine, theradio) {
  this.seats = seats;
  this.engine = engine;
  this.theradio = theradio;
}
car.prototype.payment = get_payment;
```